# Java ICEpdf default font settings

Tags: java, fonts, icepdf

I am using ICEpdf Free version for view PDF but there are bugs in font. In places where is in PDF document used embeded subset of font are incorrect chars for Czech language.

Is there any way how set the default font for ICEpdffor render if the used font isn't found?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try enabling the system property "-dorg.icepdf.core.awtFontLoading=true" which will try a little harder to load an embedded font program.  Posting a sample file on the icepdf community forms would also be helpful.

The PRO version can handle the subset correctly.